# Finding the variables (read or write)

Tags: python

I'd like to develop a small debugging tool for python programs.In Dynamic Slicing How can I find the variables that are accessed in a statement? And find the type of access (read or write) for those variables (in Python).### Write: A statement can change the program state Read : A statement can read the program state .****For example in these 4 lines we have: (1) x = a+b => write{x} & reads{a,b} (2)y=6 => write{y}&reads{} (3) while(n>1) => write{} &reads{n} (4) n=n-1 write{n} & reads{n}

Comment: I would guess that something from the `ast` module would be helpful here.  However, this isn't really well defined.  What about function calls?  `func = lambda lst,x: lst[3:] = x; x = func(lst,x)`

Comment: Could you explain your problem further? How complicated are the statements you're expecting? What is your final goal with this?

Comment: I'd like to develop a small debugging tool for python programs.In Dynamic Slicing How can I find the variables that are accessed in a statement? And find the type of access (read or write) for those variables (in Python).
Write: A statement can change the program state
Read : A statement can read the program state 
For example in these 4 lines we have:
(1) x = a+b => write{x} & reads{a,b}   (2)y=6 => write{y}&reads{}    (3) while(n>1) => write{} &reads{n}    (4) n=n-1 write{n} & reads{n}

Comment: @Srwe: you can probably squeeze out what's *explicitly* changed, but it'll be very hard to find all the variables which might be changed.  `a+b` could in principle change lots of objects, not merely `a` and `b`, because the `__add__` method of `a` could have a line like `globals()['c'] = 19` in it..

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what your goal is. Perhaps [`dis`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) is what you're looking for?

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis("x=a+b")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              3 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
              6 BINARY_ADD
              7 STORE_NAME               2 (x)
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Thanks Tim.  How can I get output of dis as dictionary?